# Finding theme files based on code pieces on Mac with Finder not working / accurate

Tags: php, macos

**Problem**

I'm experiencing regularly the problem that **my Mac isn't finding files based on given code pieces.**

For example, I was just searching for the code

```
woocommerce_account_navigation
```

which I know is in a file called class-woocommerce-template-account.php. However, my Mac doesnt present this file in the results, while it even shows other files in the same enclosing folder that contain this code.

**This is really frustrating and I wonder how other developers overcome this search problem?**

I know for certain public themes & plugins, you can search github, which is great, but this option isn't available for non-public files that you have on your computer only.

I would very much appreciate any guidance from more experienced developers and Mac users.

Many thanks

David

Comment: I use a proper IDE (PhpStorm) and dont rely (at all) on osx candy for core capabilities such as this when developing.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg thanks. Unfortunately PHP storm, while great, isn't free. Has anyone experience with Atom in terms of efficiently searching files for code and how to?

Comment: true, but in the end you get for what you pay.  I save multiple times daily in time not wasted my subscription fee.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg If I was a full-time developer, I certainly would pay for it too! I have came across PHPstorm a few times and always looked enticing.